# Process in parallel huge list

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I have some asynchronous features and would like to distribute them to process them.

1 - Suppose I have X users (logins);
2 - For each user I have to perform some tasks;

// Example

```
foreach (var login in logins)
{
     if (! await _serviceLoginInjected.LogIn (login)) // Injected service
     {
         continues;
     }

     await _serviceLoginInjected.SendEmails();
     await _serviceLoginInjected.CreateFiles();
     await _serviceLoginInjected.DoSomethingElse();
}
```

- It is very important that there is no conflict between logins;
- If some processing fails, do not impact others;
- It would be interesting to limit the amount of tasks, avoiding some overhead;

I'm really lost on how to accomplish these tasks.

Comment: Look at Parallel.ForEach ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: Parallel.ForEach, as @auburg suggested, is a good option, but beware, you won't be able to call async methods in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of batches and than create task for each item in the batch doing the work (in parallel)

```
async Task Main()
{
    var batchSize = 10;
    var batches = logins.Select((item, inx) => new { item, inx })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.inx / batchSize)
                    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.item));

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>(batchSize);
        foreach (var login  in batch)
        {
            tasks.Add(DoWork());
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

public async Task DoWork()
{
    if (await _serviceLoginInjected.LogIn(login))
    {
        await _serviceLoginInjected.SendEmails();
        await _serviceLoginInjected.CreateFiles();
        await _serviceLoginInjected.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```